# What causes an isothermal process to proceed?

Tags: thermodynamics

In this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70326/where-does-additional-heat-energy-come-from-in-isothermal-step-of-carnot-cycle?rq=1), a commenter states that it is not the heat exchange which causes the volume increase in isothermal expansion, but it is the volume increase which causes the heat exchange. If that is the case, what causes the volume increase?

If the system is to always obey the ideal gas law, then it is always in equilibrium. If we could pull the piston out manually, that could cause such an expansion. But what about when we have an independent engine running, where we aren't manually increasing the volume? Why does the isothermal expansion proceed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various thermodynamic processes come from different physical interactions with the outside world. Different conditions, different constraints, different names.

Consider a gas in perfect contact with a constant heat reservoir. It’s in a cylinder closed off up a piston, which has a pile of sand on it.

Now remove one grain of sand. The pressure, which is determined by the weight of the piston, goes down.

The piston will move up by a tiny $\Delta x$, and the gas will cool a tiny bit. But, soon enough, the heat bath will return the gas to the bath temperature. Eventually this will stabilize atthe new, smaller P, a slightly larger V, and the same T. And now you’ve had a bit of isothermal expansion: repeat as needed.

Many thermodynamic processes are driven by *external* changes. This is one example.

Comment: So when you remove the grain of sand, the volume increases and temperature decreases? This must mean that pressure also decreases to offset the volume increase and satisfy the ideal gas law. But when it heats back up from the heat bath, why don't we see the reverse change, or at least *some* backwards change?

Comment: Why would there be a reverse change? Restoring the temperature is energy flow into the gas from the resecoir

Comment: So the sand grain is removed - the volume increases, the temperature decreases, the pressure decreases. Since this happened spontaneously, it must now be in equilibrium (were it not for the heat bath), so it must satisfy the ideal gas law. Then when the heat bath raises the temperature again, shouldn't P and/or V change to keep the ideal gas law satisfied?

Comment: Exactly. PV is still the same because nkT is still the same. But P and V are each different. Reduce P, and it will stabilize at a different V.

Comment: I guess my question is - when we removed the grain of sand, that caused -dT, dV, and -dP. When the heat is added back in, we have dT - so what causes the system to restore some way other than -dV and dP? Why does it choose this new equilibrium state instead of the original one?

Comment: Because the gas does get to change P. In that configuration, P is set by the weight of the sand and the area of the piston.